# changing selenium domain/subdomain within cucumber scenarios

Tags: selenium, subdomain, cucumber, webrat

So, I have a Rails webapp that utilizes subdomains for separating the admin functionality from the public functionality using subdomain-fu. 
So there is functionality(that I want to test!) contained within two urls(eg `admin.example.com` and `www.example.com`). I want some scenarios to run against the admin domain, and some against the www domain.

My problem is that I cant figure out how to change the domain that selenium uses at any time after startup. I can put something like this in my env.rb:

```
Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :selenium
  config.application_address = "admin.example.com"
end
```

And it will work, but only for the scenarios that need the admin domain. If I try something like:

```
host! "www.example.com"
```

inside my steps, well it seems to just be ignored by selenium, which goes on using "admin.example.com"

Any ideas? Or if its not possible, any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got this working using Webrat but with Cabybara the following works for me.

```
Given /^I visit subdomain "(.+)"$/ do |sub|
  # host! "#{sub}.example.com" #for webrat
  Capybara.default_host = "#{sub}.example.com" #for Rack::Test
  Capybara.app_host = "http://#{sub}.example.com:9887" if Capybara.current_driver == :selenium

  ################################################################################
  # As far as I know, you have to put all the {sub}.example.com entries that you're
  # using in your /etc/hosts file for the Culerity tests. This didn't seem to be
  # required for Rack::Test
  ################################################################################
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used webrat but in a normal test if you were to put a full path instead of a relative path in the open it.

so

`selenium.open("http://foo/bar");` will make the test go to the full url